# Implementing Spring Security AccessDecisionManager by example

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, access-control

**Please note:** someone seems to be serially DVing my questions without explanation. This question is on topic, is not a duplicate, shows research and provides an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If you wish to DV or CV it, that's fine, but please provide a comment as to why so I can have a chance to address your concerns...

---

Spring Boot 2.3.x and Spring Security here.

I have some pretty complicated authorization logic, and so I *believe* I need to write my own `AccessDecisionManager` impl and wire it into my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` impl (if that's wrong or misunderstood in any way, **please** correct me!).

So then, to implement your own `AccessDecisionManager` you need to implement 3 methods, one of which is:

```
public class MyCustomAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {

    @Override
    public void decide(
            Authentication authentication,
            Object object,
            Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes) throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {

        // TODO

    }

}
```

I have scoured the Google Gods high and low, and for the life of me I cannot find a meaningful, real world example of what the `Object object` and `Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes` arguments are, what they are used for, how they are *intended* on being used, and what some real world (concrete) examples of them will be at runtime.

The `Authentication` argument is obvious: it is my auth token and will contain the principal, possibly their credential, and a list of `GrantedAuthorities` (permissions) associated with the principal.

**But the other two arguments (`object` and `configAttributes` ) are absolute mysteries to me.**

Does anybody know what these arguments are, what some **real world** use cases of them are, and how they are intended to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JavaDoc for `AccessDecisionManager` says:

> object – the secured object being called

Usually, it's an instance of the `MethodInvocation` interface and it represents the method for which call security decision should be performed.

> configAttributes - the configuration attributes associated with the secured object being invoked

It's a collection of metadata attributes related to the security object (Method). For example, it can contain information about annotations related to this method, such as `@PermitAll`, `@PreAuthorize`, `@PostFilter`, etc.

Comment: Ahhh thanks @Sergey (+1). So to summarize: I would add, say, `@Secured("CAN_MODIFY_FIZZBUZZ")` annotation to a controller method (say, to `FizzbuzzController#modifyFizzbuzz`), and then the `object : Object` would be a `MethodInvocation` representing `FizzbuzzController#modifyFizzbuzz`, and the `configAttributes` would be a singleton list containing the `CAN_MODIFY_FIZZBUZZ` string? Can you verify that my understanding is correct? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. According to `SecuredAnnotationMetadataExtractor` and `SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource` classes your `configAttributes` should contain `CAN_MODIFY_FIZZBUZZ`. And the Object should contain the corresponding method invocation object.